# Carry over incrementing bytes in an array

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm testing to see how easily (or quickly rather) our encryption can be cracked. The encryption key is an array of byte (could be any variable length). So, starting from an array populated with all 0's, I need to increment one byte at a time starting with the first. When any byte reaches its max and goes back to 0, the next byte in the array needs to increment (carry over).

It would be simple if the array were a short fixed length - but I'm clueless how to do so in a variable array length.

Variable declared inside the thread:

```
FKey: array of Byte;
```

After each thread iteration, it calls this procedure to increment the key by one byte:

```
procedure TCrackThread.NextKey;
begin
  //Increment first byte
  //If max, reset to 0 and increment next byte
  //Recursively check the same for each following byte in array
end;
```

How can I increment (starting from the first) the bytes and carry over to the next in this variable length array?

Comment: Note that if you had an 8 byte (64 bit) key and could test one billion keys a second then it would take almost 585 years to test all key combinations.

Comment: If you're using a known encryption method, then the cracking profile is also already known; you can just look it up instead of trying to measure it. If you're using encryption that you just made up, but you're struggling with counting, then you've probably done the encryption wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet will increase the first element and will continue to do so with the array elements as long as they are 255. If so, they are reset to zero. The routine will stop as soon as the condition is not fulfilled or the index reached maximum.

```
var
  k: Integer;
...
if (Length(fKey) > 0) then begin
  k := 0;
  Inc(fKey[k]);
  while (fKey[k] = 255) do begin
    fKey[k] := 0;
    Inc(k);
    if (k >= Length(fKey)) then
      break;
    Inc(fKey[k]);
  end;
end;
```

This would convert an array 254,0,0 into 0,1,0

If you want a carry to ripple through before the first increment,
this code will do that:

```
procedure Next;
var
  k: Integer;
  carry: Boolean;
begin
  if (Length(fKey) > 0) then begin
    k := 0;
    repeat
      carry := (fKey[k] = 255);
      if carry then begin
        fKey[k] := 0;
        Inc(k);
        if (k >= Length(fKey)) then
          break;
      end
      else
        Inc(fKey[k]);
    until not carry;
  end;
end;
```

This will convert 255,255,0 into 0,0,1.

Comment: As I read your code, an array of 254,0,0 would increment to 0,1,0 not 255,0,0 as I believe the OP wants

Comment: @crefird, "Increment first byte" 254 -> 255. "If max, reset to 0 and increment next byte". I believe my inperpretation meets what the OP wants.

Comment: @crefird, reading the second sentence in the question, it looks like the logic is a bit ambiguous. I updated the answer with an example covering your interpretation.

Comment: This can be generalized a bit. Carry should be set if the result < one of the operands. Then an overflow has taken place.

Comment: @Rudy, yes I know, or just check for zero after increment. I was just trying to avoid the overflow RT error if this compiler flag is on. It is easy to turn it off for this routine though if someone is interested. I made a speed comparison and difference is just a few percent. For real speed, a few assembly lines would take care of this.

Comment: I meant a real addition, not just an increment. If you let the values wrap around, then if the result is less than any of the operands, there was an overflow and you should set the carry. If the result is >= any of the operands, there was no carry.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, You lost me there. If you replace the 255 with 0 in my first snippet and remove next line with the assignment to 0, isn't that what you mean?

Comment: No, I meant it more generally when adding any array to another array.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I know how big integer addition works, but how could that help here, when we always are adding 1?